# Logging observable values while extending service

Tags: logging, typescript, redux, angular-2+, rxjs

I'm trying to extend a service function which returns an `Observable<T>`. The idea is to extend the function so I can add logging functionality whenever the observable emits a new value.

```
fromEvent<T>(eventName: string): Observable<T> {
    super.fromEvent(eventName).subscribe(
        function next(data) {
            console.group();
                console.log('----- SOCKET INBOUND -----');
                console.log('Action: ', eventName);
                console.log('Payload: ', data);
            console.groupEnd();
        }
    );

    return super.fromEvent(eventName);
```

How can I make my function more effective? Because whenever `fromEvent()` is invoked a subscription is created and an observable is returned from the base class. As I understand, all subscriptions should at some point be unsubscribed.

Or are there any other way you could implement a logging functionality on an observable that listens to a specific event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve what you want is to use `.do()` and may be `.catch()` operators.

`.do()` operator taps on a target stream and executes a function on each non-error event in the stream. It is designed specifically for this purpose, which you can define more generically as *side effects*:

> This method can be used for debugging, logging, etc. of query behavior by intercepting the message stream to run arbitrary actions for messages on the pipeline. -- [RxJs docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/do.md)

Notice that `.do()`:

1. **does NOT affect the original Observable** stream in any way. This function itself returns an `Observable` of the same type as the original one.
2. **does NOT subscribe to the original `Observable`**, so the `.subscribe()` invocation is required down the road.
3. **does NOT react to error events** in the original `Observable`. Therefore, you may want to use `.catch()` to log the errors.

---

```
fromEvent<T>(eventName: string): Observable<T> {
  return super
    .fromEvent(eventName)
    .do(eventData => {
      console.group();
      console.log('----- SOCKET INBOUND -----');
      console.log('Action: ', eventName);
      console.log('Payload: ', eventData);
      console.groupEnd();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.group();
      console.error('----- SOCKET INBOUND -----');
      console.error('Action: ', eventName);
      console.error('Error: ', error);
      console.groupEnd();
    });
}
```

Comment: I use '.do()' almost daily with ngrx/effects, can't believe I couldn't connect the dots :). Thanks tremendously for your help!

Comment: @AndreasJohansson yeah, no problem. This happens to all of us time to time.